# Convert feet and inches to decimal format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, converters, vba

I have approximately 3600 heights with the format Feet-Inch-Inch-Eigth of an inch, so for example:

```
5103 = 5 feet, 10 and 3/8 inches
6000 = 6 feet
6022 = 6 feet, 2 and 2/8 inches
```

and I need to convert these to decimal format either with a formula or macro, so that the results for these would be:

```
5103 = 5.864
6000 = 6.000
6022 = 6.187
```

As I have 3600+ of these, manual work would be a pain. How can I convert this format to a decimal format of feet and inches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=--LEFT(A1,1)+MID(A1,2,2)/12+RIGHT(A1,1)/(12*8)
```

and copy down:

[image]

NOTE:

this conversion yields decimal feet so that ***2 feet 6 inches*** shows ***2.5***

**EDIT#1:**

If you need to accommodate more than **9** feet in column **A**, then the formula should be:

```
=--LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)+MID(A1,LEN(A1)-2,2)/12+RIGHT(A1,1)/(12*8)
```

Comment: works like a charm provided your height in feet is never more than single digit.  if you had 10' or more things will blow up!

Comment: @ForwardEd  You are correct..........we would need to check the length of the argument and make adjustments.

Comment: @ForwardEd  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @ForwardEd correct, but as these are human heights, that is very unlikely

Comment: @MJ95 sorry, did not realize we were talking about people.  As such was just looking at the general approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever need to go the long route, a VBA UDF would seem to be the most expedient.

```
Function feet2dec(str As String) As Double
    Dim v As Long, vtmp As Variant, tmp As String
    Dim feet As Double

    vtmp = Split(str, Chr(44))
    For v = LBound(vtmp) To UBound(vtmp)
        Select Case LCase(Right(Trim(vtmp(v)), 4))
            Case "feet"
                feet = feet + Val(Trim(Replace(vtmp(v), "feet", vbNullString, 1, -1, vbTextCompare)))
            Case "ches"
                str = Replace(vtmp(v), "inches", vbNullString, 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
                str = Application.Trim(Replace(str, "and", vbNullString, 1, -1, vbTextCompare))
                feet = feet + Application.Evaluate(str) / 12
        End Select
    Next v

    feet2dec = feet
End Function
```

[image: feet2dec]

Comment: Nice use of *Val()* and *Evaluate()*